# TypeGuards for optional property while filtering array of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter, typeguards

I've got the following interfaces in typescript:

```js
interface ComplexRating {
  ratingAttribute1?: number;
  ratingAttribute2?: number;
  ratingAttribute3?: number;
  ratingAttribute4?: number;
}

export interface Review {
  rating: ComplexRating | number;
}
```

I'd love to calculate an average rating for say `ratingAttribute1` for sake of simplicity.

So given these reviews:

```js
const reviews: Review[] = [
  { rating: { ratingAttribute1: 5 } },
  { rating: { ratingAttribute1: 10 } },
  { rating: { ratingAttribute2: 15 } },
  { rating: 5 }
]
```

I can filter down the reviews to the ones I'm interested in i.e.:

```js
const calculateAverageRating = (reviews: Review[]): number => {
  const reviewsWithRating = reviews.filter(
    (review) =>
      typeof review.rating === 'object' &&
      typeof review.rating['ratingAttribute1'] === 'number'
  );
  return (
    reviewsWithRating.reduce((acc, review) => {
      let newValue = acc;
      if (typeof review.rating === 'object') {
        const rating = review.rating['ratingAttribute1'];
        if (rating) {
          newValue += rating;
        }
      }
      return newValue;
    }, 0.0) / reviewsWithRating.length
  );
};
```

Now, what's annoying is that Typescript does not know that by running the `reviews.filter` function I type guarded the Reviews only to a subset of the Reviews that have `rating of type ComplexType` and also the ones that have `ratingAttribute1: number;`  rather than `ratingAttribute?: number`.

What I'd love to end up with is not having to repeat the type checks in the calculation effectively ending up with:

```js
const calculateAverageRating = (reviews: Review[]): number => {
  const reviewsWithRating = reviews.filter(
    (review) =>
      typeof review.rating === 'object' &&
      typeof review.rating['ratingAttribute1'] === 'number'
  );
  return (
    reviewsWithRating.reduce(
      (acc, review) => acc + review.rating['ratingAttribute1'],
      0.0
    ) / reviewsWithRating.length
  );
};
```

but that does not work out of the box:
[image]

Is there any way of achieving this level of type guarding? Or is there a neater of way doing this type of stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.filter()` function will always return an array of the same type that was given as the argument. That is why `reviewsWithRating` is still a `Review[]`, even after you filter it.

To change this, you can add a [type guard](https://type%20guard) to the callback:

```
const reviewsWithRating = reviews.filter(
  (review): review is { rating: Required<ComplexRating> } =>
    typeof review.rating === 'object' &&
    typeof review.rating['ratingAttribute1'] === 'number'
);
```

Now TypeScript will know that `reviewsWithRating` is of type `{ rating: Required<ComplexRating> }[]`.

Comment: I see! It's obvious that I can return the type guard inlined ‍♂️. The use of Required is new to me, now that makes sense.

Comment: There's one caveat to it, it does not necessarily guard against mistakes, if I perform the filter as such:

```
  const reviewsWithRating = reviews.filter(
    (review): review is {
      rating: Required<WorkCarriedOutRating>;
      dateCreated: Timestamp;
    } => typeof review.rating === 'object'
  );
```
It lets it through without knowing that I did not perform the check whether the value is a number or not. I wonder why that is.

Comment: That is correct. When you are using a type guard, TypeScript will let you do almost anything without further checks.